# Activating link without a browser

Tags: python, urllib

I have a webpage where I am a registered user. I need to log in without a browser(username,password) and click a link which adds my name to a list on the webpage. I want this process to work in the background e.g. not show up on the screen at all. I've been trying to use Python to do this e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#coding:utf-8

import sys 
import urllib 
import urllib2 
import urlparse 
import subprocess

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US;
    rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15'

def process(url):
    myopener = MyOpener()
    page = myopener.open(url)

    text = page.read()
    page.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    links = []

    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        links.append(tag['href'])

    return links

if __name__ == "__main__":
    links = process("http://www.dropbox.com")
    for link in links:
        #print link
        if 'downloading' in link:
            print link
            fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen(link)
```

Comment: In the code I am trying to activate the download link on dropbox homepage so the program will be downloaded. Is that possible?

Comment: to Uku Loskit:   the Python code doesn't activate the link in the sense that the Dropbox program is downloaded to my computer.

Comment: It is impossible to help you without more information.  How are authentication credentials stored? If its public, you need to tell us the actual site so we can see. I will give an answer for a general, reasonably well designed site below.

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples for an example of http authentication. Not sure if this is what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML code of the page with the button. If there is a url/link behind a button you just have to do a GET on this link, eg with urllib2.

If there is some javascript triggered by the button urllib2 will not help you. One way to solve this problem could be to use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.html#introducing-selenium), I never used it, but it is supposed to be very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how exactly you do this depends on the site in question.  However, I will assume that you need to create a new session every time and that the servier issues a session id which is stored in your cookies upon successful authentication.

1. Work out if the login page expects GET or POST parameters
2. Perform the login and store the session id returned (Set-Cookie in server response)
3. Work out what request is sent to the server when you click that link.
4. Send that request yourself, the server cannot tell the difference.
5. Logout again if you want to loop this more frequently than session timeout.

Using a proxy such as Burp or mitmproxy will help you debug any issues.

If you discover that the GET request sent by clicking that link does not change over time or with each new login, then you can determine that beforehand. Then you can simply login to grab the cookie, not bother with the page contents, and just fire off the GET request as soon as you have the cookie you need to send along with that request.

Good luck, have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can look for [PAMIE](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/), an easy IE Python automation tool

Simple PAMIE example:

```
import cPAMIE as PAMIE
ie = PAMIE( )
ie.Navigate("'www.google.com" )
ie.textBoxSet("q", "python" )
ie.buttonClick("'btnG" )
```

The 3.0 version of PAMIE is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Web-Unit/PAMIE/src/PAM30.py.htm)